# How to test StreamSubscription and create Events in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to write some unit tests around an abstract `Uploader` class that I have written like so:

```
abstract class Uploader {
  Future<StreamSubscription> subscribe(String filename, void onEvent(Event event));
}

class FirebaseUploader implements Uploader {
  Future<StreamSubscription> subscribe(String filename, void onEvent(Event event)) async {
    String userId = await auth.signInAnonymously();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = _databaseReference(userId, filename);
    return databaseReference.onValue.listen(onEvent);
  }
}

class UploaderMock implements Uploader {

  Future<StreamSubscription> subscribe(String filename, void onEvent(Event event)) async {

    Event event = new Event(); // The class 'Event' doesn't have a default constructor.
    return Future.value(null);
  }
}
```

The trouble is, I can't work out how to create my own `Event`s in my `UploaderMock`, so I can call `onEvent`. If I try to create a `new Event()`, I get the following error:

*The class 'Event' doesn't have a default constructor.*

This is because `Event` has a **private** constructor:

```
Event._(this._data) : snapshot = new DataSnapshot._(_data['snapshot']);
```

This makes sense for production, but it doesn't really work for testing.

Any ideas? How can I test code that uses `StreamSubscription`?

Answer (score 1):

You can *implements* `Event` on a custom class.

```
class Bar {
  Bar._() {}
}

class Foo implements Bar {
  Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can't, but you can make them public and annotate it with
> @visibleForTesting to get an DartAnalyzer warning when they are
> accessed from code that is not in in the same library or in test/

answered here [How to test private functions/methods in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219835/how-to-test-private-functions-methods-in-flutter/54219882#54219882)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33363302)

Comment: thanks for the review, comment changed.